# Can you pass events as parameters to functions?

Tags: solidity

I got the error:

```
ParserError: Expected type name
```

when I used following the following convention to pass an event as a function parameter:

```
  event MyEvent(string s1, string s2);

  function _emitEvent(event eventName) internal {
    emit eventName('hello', 'world');
  {

  function otherFunc() public {
    _emitEvent(MyEvent);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't do that as of Solidity version 0.4.24.

Solidity supports function types, but not event types.

You can read more about this here: https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html